# SQL Server function to eliminate replicated characters

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005, string

I wonder if there is an easy and efficient way in SQL Server 2005 to eliminate replicated characters in a string. Like converting

```
'ABBBCDEEFFFFG' to 'ABCDEFG'
```

It really sucks that SQL Server has such a poor string library and no ready-to-use regexp feature...

Comment: It does have CLR function support though, which supports Regex.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to bother with C# or VB.Net and compile it and deploy it and so on. Moreover, my user role for this particular DB is just querying, I don't have developer privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CLR functionality built into SQL Server 2005/2008 to get this done by .NET code.

MSDN magazine wrote about it in their [February 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) issue.

If this is not an acceptable solution, [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) is a UDF that will do the same, mind you this is about two orders of magnitude slower than the CLR solution.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV. This appears to work for your string above. But not `ABBBCDEEBBBBG`

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @Numbers (Num)
SELECT TOP 8000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.NAME)
FROM
    sys.columns c1

DECLARE @STuff TABLE (Seq varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @STuff (Seq) VALUES ('ABBBCDEEFFFFG') --works

SELECT
    Single
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CAST(Single AS varchar(100))
    FROM
       @Numbers N
       CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT Seq, SUBSTRING(Seq, Num, 1) AS Single FROM @Stuff) S
    WHERE
       Num <= LEN(Seq)
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) foo(Single)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know about the CLR solution, but as I said, I am neither responsible nor authorized to implement it in the DB of question.

For this particular problem, I decided to write a very simple and kinda silly loop. I am afraid it won't be fast enough for millions of records, but anyways... I wish I could do this stuff in the application layer but I am bound to T-SQL here..

```
  DECLARE @i int ;  -- counter
  DECLARE @input varchar(200) ;
  SET @input = 'AAABCDEEFFBBBXYZSSSWWWNT'

  IF LEN(@input) > 1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @unduplicated varchar(200) ;
    SET @unduplicated = SUBSTRING(@input,1,1) ;

    SET @i = 2 ;
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@input)
    BEGIN
      -- If current char is different from the last char, concatenate, else not
      IF SUBSTRING(@unduplicated, LEN(@unduplicated), 1) <> SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1)
        SET @unduplicated = @unduplicated + SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1) ;
      SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
  END  
  SELECT @unduplicated AS unduplicated;
```

Result:

```
unduplicated 
ABCDEFBXYZSWNT
```